# Indentation in TOC and Lists of Figures/Tables

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I am just starting to use Latex to write a university report. It does feel like a steep learning curve, and is at times frustrating, but I guess it is because I'm very new to it.

I got a question regarding TOC/figures/tables.

Basically, my document structure currently gets displayed in TOC as follows:

```
  Contributions *section*
  Summary *section*
  List of Figures *section*
  List of Tables *section*
1 Introduction *chapter*
  1.1 Background *section*
  1.2 Other Section *section*
2 Other Chapter *chapter*
```

However, I'd like it to be displayed like this:

```
Contributions
Summary
List of Figures
List of Tables
1 Introduction
  1.1 Background
  1.2 Other Section
2 Other Chapter
```

Notice, that the first four unnumbered sections are not indented, but keep the indentation of numbered sections. Also, related to this question. I'd like my Lists of Tables/Figures to be NOT indented.

For example, instead of this:

```
List of Figures
   1. Caption ------------------------------------------ 4
```

Have this:

```
List of Figures
1. Caption --------------------------------------------- 4
```

Thanks for you help!

** EDIT (added more info)

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Remove "Chapter" from title. No break between # and name.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
\bfseries\Large\thechapter.\quad\ #1
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\section*{Contributions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contributions}

This is a contributions sections. 

\section*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}

This is a summary section.

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents %TOC

\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures} %List of Figures

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}

Welcome to introduction chapter.

\section{Background}

This is a background section.\ref{capt}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample Figure.}
\label{capt}  %must be after caption
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `tocloft` package is probably a good start for you here.

Comment: We need more information -- e.g. your documentclass and the way you insert unnumbered chapters into the ToC. A minimal working example would be even better.

Comment: @Raphink Thanks, I will take a look at it.  
  
@lockstep Please see my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did.

As it was suggested by @Raphink, I used `tocloft` package. All of the sections that I wanted to be at the top level of my TOC (such as contributions, summary, references, etc) I included in TOC as parts. This is because I haven't found a way to adjust only certain sections without changing all sections in TOC. I also don't have any parts in my report, so it doesn't conflict with any existing items.

Then, in order to format them correctly (as regular sections, but with no indentation) I used the following:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont} % make parts look like sections in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{0pt} % remove spaces before and after chapters
```

It looks a little clumsy, so if someone knows a better solution, please post your reply.

As for LoF and LoT, I used the following:

```
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot
```

Hope someone else finds it helpful!

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternative solution for removing the default indentation in your list of figures / tables. This solution has the advantage of avoiding the `tocloft` package, which often disrupts the default formatting of the table of contents in unexpected ways. Try adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}% Default: 1.5em/2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother
```

Comment: I had the problem that the ravil's answer lead to *some* indented rows (mostly when two lined captions). This fixed it.

Comment: How to use this for a list of listings?

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm.