# Remove space before item in table of figures and other listofs

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, indentation

I am looking to remove the space before each item in listoffigures, listoftables, etc.

Here is what I want to do :

[image: The unwilling space before item in lof, lot]

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, dvipsnames, openany, twoside]{book}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
%\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Structure
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

% Color
\colorlet{maincolor}{Red}

% Lists : settings

    % Set "listof" as sections and not as chapters
    \addtotoclist[float]{lof}
    \renewcommand*\listoffigures{\listoftoc[{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
    \addtotoclist[float]{lot}
    \renewcommand*\listoftables{\listoftoc[{\listtablename}]{lot}}
    \makeatletter
    \doforeachtocfile[float]{\setuptoc{\@currext}{leveldown}}
    \makeatother

    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~--~}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{Figure~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{Tableau~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

    \renewcommand\frenchtablename{}
    \renewcommand{\frenchlistfigurename}{Liste des figures}

% Figure

\newcommand{\myfigure}[2][]{\ifstrempty{#1}{\tcbincludegraphics{#2}}{\tcbincludegraphics[arc=8pt, width=7cm, colframe=maincolor, step and label={figure}{fig:#1}, title=\textbf{\thefigure~--~{#1}}, phantom={\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{#1}}},]{#2}}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Beginning of document
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Table des illustrations}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Illustrations diverses}

\section{Première section}

\lipsum[1]
\myfigure[Figure test]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clean solution without packages here :

[Indentation in TOC and Lists of Figures/Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/indentation-in-toc-and-lists-of-figures-tables)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}% Default: 1.5em/2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`. So you can change the indent of the entries, with `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` and attribute `indent`. But the problem with your code is, that you use `section` entries for the figures instead of `figure`. So you also have to change this.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, dvipsnames, openany, twoside]{book}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
%\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Structure
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

% Color
\colorlet{maincolor}{Red}

% Lists : settings

    % Set "listof" as sections and not as chapters
    \addtotoclist[float]{lof}
    \renewcommand*\listoffigures{\listoftoc[{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
    \addtotoclist[float]{lot}
    \renewcommand*\listoftables{\listoftoc[{\listtablename}]{lot}}
    \makeatletter
    \doforeachtocfile[float]{\setuptoc{\@currext}{leveldown}}
    \makeatother

    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~--~}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{Figure~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{Tableau~\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

    \renewcommand\frenchtablename{}
    \renewcommand{\frenchlistfigurename}{Liste des figures}

% Figure

\newcommand{\myfigure}[2][]{\ifstrempty{#1}{\tcbincludegraphics{#2}}{\tcbincludegraphics[arc=8pt,
    width=7cm, colframe=maincolor, step and label={figure}{fig:#1},
    title=\textbf{\thefigure~--~{#1}},
    phantom={\addcontentsline{lof}
      {figure}% CHANGED
      {\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{#1}}},]{#2}}}

\newcommand*{\numberwithhyphen}[1]{#1~--~}% ADDED (You could use this also to add `\figurename` before the number, if you'd also adapt numwidth attribute.)

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt,numwidth=5.5em,entrynumberformat=\numberwithhyphen]{tocline}{figure}% ADDED

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Beginning of document
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Table des illustrations}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Illustrations diverses}

\section{Première section}

\lipsum[1]
\myfigure[Figure test]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`.

BTW: `tocbasic` also provides a feature to prefix entries by a string like `Figure`. So adding this to `\thefigure` would not be needed, if it results in issues with other usage of `\thefigure`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. Indeed, your suggestion broke my formating : I no longer see the hyphen : "Figure 1.1 Figure test", the hyphen is missing.

Comment: @Dorian As I already said: See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`. Style `tocline` has a lot of additional features. I've now also demonstrated the `entrynumberformat` feature. But I'm sure, someone who already uses `tocbasic`, is would have been able to find this too.

Comment: no, there is still a problem with the solutions you are suggesting to me: the caption does not follow the text of the caption so it overlaps. look what happens when i change figure by myfigure `\newcommand*{\numberwithhyphen}[1]{MyFigure~#1~--~}% ADDED`

Comment: @Dorian What do you think is the purpose of the numwidth attribute in the example I gave? It seems you still have not read the manual. So once again: If you want additional chances, read the manual. For example, there is also an attribute for dynamic/automatic number width. Use it, if you like.